# Reconstruct Tree view from List<DirectoryInfo>

Tags: c#, list, treeview, directoryinfo

I have a function GetDirectories() which returns me the List of directory info : Now i need to reconstruct a tree view out of it , based on the its parent

Here is my function  `Getdirectories` which return the `List`:

```
public List<DirectoryInfo> GetDirectories() 
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\python_code");
        folders.Clear();
        FullDirList(di, "*");
        return folders;
    }
 static List<DirectoryInfo> folders = new List<DirectoryInfo>(); // List that hold direcotries that cannot be accessed
 static void GetFullDirList(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern))
            {
                files.Add(f);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            folders.Add(d);
            FullDirList(d, searchPattern);
        }

    }
```

I need something like this to be constructed from the List  , which contain all the DirectoryInfo elements i.e it contains its parent info also .

[image: Tree View of List<DirectoryInfo>]

so far i am trying to get the elements whose parent are same and populate it to tree view and do it recursively : 
But i am not able to get the recursive function written through .

I know their other easier ways to do the same , but this is a recruitment of a big picture i am trying to draw  . 
any help would be extremly appretiated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have WinForms treeview you can use the key argument of the [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the [`Nodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to build up your hierarchy. You don't need recursion for that. Here is the Add method:

```
    void Add(DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        if (di.Parent != null )
        {
            // find our parent node
            var node = treeView1.Nodes.Find(di.Parent.FullName,true);
            if (node.Length == 0)
            {
                // not found, add it as root
                // FullName becomes the key
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(di.FullName, di.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                // not sure what is going on if node.Length > 1
                // anyway, add it to the first node, to be our parent
                node[0].Nodes.Add(di.FullName, di.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(di.FullName, di.Name);
        }
    }
```

And a simple iterator will drive this method:

```
        var list = GetDirectories();
        foreach(var di in list)
        {
            Add(di);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . . +1 for a clean and simple way , but i need to add a tree node instead of simple string , which will have each node as directoryinfo , so that i need not to do a search it's parent . doing so  var node = treeView1.Nodes.Find(di.Parent.FullName,true); is not working for me

Comment: You should be able to set the `FullPath` of your treeNode to di.FullName and with that I expect to be findable.